# Autofill forms in Bitcoin protocol

Tags: protocol

For example, I have link: 
`bitcoin:1DF9jgzftTFn4ZnDV2YEjUtZ4uHtBywj57`. If user open this link in browser, bitcoin address automatically insert in address text field. Example for my MultiBit Classic client:

[image: Bitcoin send]

But what should I make in link to have been autocomplete not only field `Address` but also fields `Label` and `Amount`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard for Bitcoin URI schemes, and it is defined by [BIP 21](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0021.mediawiki).

However, that does not mean that every wallet application out there will support all the fields when it it opened from a link.  Most will, but don't be surprised if some fields don't fill in automatically.